# Import of external class in Kotlin Gradle Script not found

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In my `build.gradle.kts`, I want to write a function that uses an external class: `StrSubstitutor` from Apach Commons Text. However, the import is not found, although I can see the library when I run `./gradlew dependencies`.

The `build.gradle.kts` file is as follows:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinSourceSet
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor // Import not found

plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.3.61"
    kotlin("jvm") version "$kotlinVersion"
    kotlin("kapt") version "$kotlinVersion"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.8")

    // SourceSets
    sourceSets.main {
        withConvention(KotlinSourceSet::class) {
            kotlin.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin")
        }
    }
    sourceSets.test {
        withConvention(KotlinSourceSet::class) {
            kotlin.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin")
        }
    }

}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
    systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

// Function that uses the import
fun getProperty(properties: Properties, propertyKey: String): String {
    // Use the import "StrSubstitutor"
    return ""
}
```

Is this possible with Kotlin, and if so: how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The reason it does not work as written is because you put the dependency on the Apache Commons Text into `implementation` configuration of the *project*, not into the `classpath` of the *build script* itself. So, you basically need to introduce a `buildscript` block to your build.gradle.kts file. Below is an example<sup>1</sup>:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinSourceSet
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor

// TL DR: Add this block to your build script to make the import above work
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.8")
    }
}

tasks.register("hello") {
    doLast {
        println(StringSubstitutor.replaceSystemProperties(
            "You are running with Java \${java.version} on OS \${os.name}."))
    }
}

plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.3.61"
    kotlin("jvm") version "$kotlinVersion"
    kotlin("kapt") version "$kotlinVersion"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // You probably do not need this for your project, so I commented it out
//    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.8")

    // SourceSets
    sourceSets.main {
        withConvention(KotlinSourceSet::class) {
            kotlin.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin")
        }
    }
    sourceSets.test {
        withConvention(KotlinSourceSet::class) {
            kotlin.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin")
        }
    }

}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
    systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

Run this script with `./gradlew -q hello` to check whether it works or not.

<sup>1</sup> New task `hello` exists there just to demonstrate that the import works, it is not needed in the final build script that you would use in your project.